# giving my little search engine a "no file was found" messenge

Tags: node.js

I have a simple JS code meant to be executed in Node.js for searching all text files in folders and sub folders.

I would like to add a "no files were found" message if no text files exist,
any ideas?

```html
var path = require('path'), fs=require('fs');

function fromDir(startPath,filter){

    if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)){
        console.log("no dir ",startPath);
        return;
    }
    var files=fs.readdirSync(startPath);
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var filename=path.join(startPath,files[i]);
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(filename);
        if (stat.isDirectory()){
            fromDir(filename,filter); 
        }
        else if (filename.indexOf(filter)>=0) {
            console.log('-- found: ',filename);
        };
    };
};

fromDir('../yoyo','.txt');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var path = require('path'), fs=require('fs');

function fromDir(startPath,filter){

    if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)){
        console.log("no dir ",startPath);
        return;
    }
    var files=fs.readdirSync(startPath);
    var found = false; // Initialize to no files found
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var filename=path.join(startPath,files[i]);
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(filename);
        if (stat.isDirectory()){
            fromDir(filename,filter); 
        }
        else if (filename.indexOf(filter)>=0) {
            found = true; // Any files found indicates no message later
            console.log('-- found: ',filename);
        };
    };
    if (!found) { // Only log if no files were found
        console.log("No file was found");
    }
};

fromDir('../yoyo','.txt');
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help @Anatsu ! Please remember to accept the answer if it helped you find a solution.